# Display game over statement

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to display a game over text once a particular game score is reached but i can't seem to get it to appear.

```
<svg id="canvas" width="600" height="600">
<text id="left" x="135" y="70" font-size = 60 font-family = "Menlo, sans-serif" fill="white">0</text>
<text id= "right" x= "435" y = "70" font-size = 60 font-family = "Menlo, sans-serif" fill = "white">0</text>
<div id= "game-over" x = "100" y = "100" font-size = 40 font-family = "Menlo, sans-serif" fill = "white"> Winner:</div>
</svg>
```

The left score would be based on the id "left" and right score would be based on id "right" and when any of these score reach 2, i want the game over statement with id "game-over" to display the winner on the html canvas.

In Javascript i tried to get the left player to win:

```
    function declareWinner(score_left:HTMLElement) {
        let max_point:number = 2;
        let winner = document.getElementById("game-over")!;
        if (score_left.innerHTML == max_point.toString()) {
            winner.innerHTML += "Left Player";
        }
    }
```

but the winner text is not displayed when the particular score is reached.

Comment: There is no html canvas in there... And your svg markup is invalid: `<div>` is not part of the svg elements list.

Answer (score 0):

@Kaiido's comment is a solution. It says:

> There is no html canvas in there...

Because the `<svg>` is not HTML canvas as you said in the question.

> i want the game over statement with id "game-over" to display the winner on the html canvas.

And the problem is that you're using `div` inside `svg`, which is not supported.

> And your svg markup is invalid:  is not part of the svg elements

So replacing it with text, should work:

```
<text id="game-over" x="100" y="100" font-size="40" font-family="Menlo, sans-serif" fill="white">Winner:</text>
```

Also make sure you're not displaying white text on white background or something color-related, because your texts are `fill="white"`.

Comment: is it possible for the WINNER statement to only appear on the svg after the scores hit a certain point?